# Where I can find canada postal codes geographic data? KML or something similar

Tags: google-visualization, geospatial, geocoding, geo

Where I can find canada postal codes geographic data? KML or something similar.

I can find US KML format geographic data here :

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/kml/kml_zcta.html

I need something similar for canada, any suggestion ?

Comment: best asked on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Shapefile: https://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1

(KML format is on the premium section)